# Отправка POST запроса с помощью JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте с помощью POST, вываливает ошибка

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: www.filmpro.ru/club/login/`

Собственно сам запрос:

```
POST /club/login HTTP/1.1  
Host: www.filmpro.ru  
Connection: close  
Content-Length: 44  
Accept: */*  
Origin: https://www.filmpro.ru  
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,   like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36  
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
Referer: https://www.filmpro.ru/  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7  
Cookie: app=eyJleHBpcmVzIjoxNTM3NTI1NjAxfQ---- 
 b328b1958dda4006ce4f2b105a97494d057e6651  

login=мой_логин&password=пароль
```

Пытаюсь обработать с помощью JSOUP:

```
Document connection = Jsoup.connect("www.filmpro.ru/club/login/")
        .header("Accept", "*/*")
        .header("Origin", "https://www.filmpro.ru")
        .header("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest")
        .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .header("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate")
        .header("Accept-Language","ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7")
        .data("login","логин")
        .data("password","пароль")
        .referrer("https://www.filmpro.ru/")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36")
        .post();

System.out.println(connection);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому, что [URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) должен содержать *схему*:

```
Jsoup.connect("https://www.filmpro.ru/club/login/")
```